# Chrome Extension for syntax highlighting in Gmail?

Tags: chrome, gmail

I get lots of email diffs from various projects that I work on. Reading these diffs in the Gmail interface can be a bit of a slog without basic features like syntax highlighting. Does anyone know something like a Chrome Extension that can do syntax highlighting inside arbitrary websites so I can see these things in a usable fashion?

I'm specifically looking for gmail but arbitrary websites is fine for posterity.

Comment: If you are familiar with *css* you can create your own stylesheet for GMail which highlight what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it does not have the same ample supply of languages that some of the file-extension-based highlighters like [Syntaxtic](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/syntaxtic/cgjalgdhmbpaacnnejmodfinclbdgaci) and [Sight](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sight/epmaefhielclhlnmjofcdapbeepkmggh) do, [**Instant Syntax**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/instant-syntax/gjoffkgdelmaodajhoncmleiamifdcgi) supports "Java, Markup Languages, CSS, C-like languages, C#, C++,Python, SQL, PHP and JavaScript." and lets you highlight text and click a button to see it colored according to the language syntax of your choice. I use it on [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) from time to time and can verify it works.

Comment: This is a pretty good solution. I know I'm not going to get everything I want and this seems to be a close as I'm going to get.